# Button in JavaScript not active / undefined

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I added an event listener to my button and assigned it a variable. However, it is not functioning. The console keeps showing undefined with no code issues at the same time which makes it complex to figure out.

This is the html markup:

```
<button value="button" id="myBtn">Click to See</button>
```

Here is the JavaScript declaration for button to call the function "action" on click:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", action);
```

Yet the console shows I got no issues and still shows btn undefined. Don't know how to fix it.

html :

```
<div>
        <h3>ZooMoji</h3>
        <img src="moji1.jpg" id="pic1">
       <img src="moji2.jpg" id="pic2"> 
       <button value="button" id="myBtn">Click to See</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var swap1 = document.getElementById("pic1").src;
var swap2 = document.getElementById("pic2").src;
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", action);
    
function action() {
   if (swap1.endsWith("moji1.jpg") == true) {
    swap1.src = swap2;
    
   }
   
   
}
```

Comment: `var swap1 = document.getElementById("pic1").src;` <-- you set swap1 to a string. And you somehow think the string has a `src`? `swap1.src = swap2;`

Comment: Where is your JavaScript? Is it in the `head` of your HTML file? It sounds like you're calling the script before the DOM has completely loaded. Take a look at the [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) documentation on to either defer the script, or move the script to the bottom of the page instead.

Comment: Just a suggestion: For me, rather than changing the img src, I generally prefer to load both/all images and use the `display` style to hide/show the right images. This way, you don't have to reload every time

Comment: Add some console logs to check the state at various places. E.g after the vars to check their values, and inside the function to make sure it’s being called.

Comment: In case anyone has similar issues and stumbled on this. I worked on the code some more and this is what worked:                                                                                              JS: let swap1 = document.getElementById("pic1");
let swap2 = document.getElementById("pic2");
let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", action);
function action() {
   if (swap1.src == document.getElementById("pic1").src) {
    swap1.src = "moji2.jpg";
    
   }
   
   
   console.log(btn);
}

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're getting the value of the `.addEventListner` function and not the actual `.getElementById`.
Do this instead.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", action);
```

And also scrap those `var`'s they're old and should in 99.9% of cases be replaced by either `const` or `let` if you want it to be mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the event listener will work fine, and the function `action` will be executed whenever you click the button, try this:

```js
function action() {
  if (swap1.endsWith("moji1.jpg") == true) {
    swap1.src = swap2;
  }

  console.log("the click event is working fine!")
}
```

The reason why the `btn` variable is returning `undefined` is the event listener itself which returns a `void`, if you are using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) try to hover over the `btn` variable and you would see something like this:

```
var btn: void
```

So in order to get an `HTMLElement` from the `btn` variable just do that:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"); // returns HTMLElement
btn.addEventListener("click", action); // returns void

function action() {
  if (swap1.endsWith("moji1.jpg") == true) {
    swap1.src = swap2;
  }
}
```

For more details: [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)